# Regex search the name

Tags: regex

I need to get the name of a class

```
Class AAA.GitHub Extends %RegisteredObject
{
// some code
```

The part I want to find is AAA.GitHub. It is very easy to find: `\bClass\b\s*(\w*(\.\w*)*)`
However, sometimes people put comments on top of the class definition like this

```
/// some comments
/* some more
   Some more text
and more
*/
Class AAA.GitHub Extends %RegisteredObject
{
// some code
```

The problem is that these comments can contain the word class. How can I workaround this ?

Comment: What is the environment? Try `^Class\b\s*(\w*(\.\w*)*)`

Comment: It is Cache Object Script but regular expressions work the same as everywhere =)

Comment: *regular expressions work the same as everywhere* is a false statement, they work differently across languages/flavors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, what about the second type of comments /* */? This regex doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid matching `Class` inside single-line comments, you may use a `^` start of *line* anchor:

```
(?m)^Class\b\s*(\w*(\.\w*)*)
```

The `(?m)` denotes a [`MULTILINE` option](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_regexp#GCOS_regexp_modes) that forces `^` to match the start of the line.

The pattern might be also written as `(?m)^Class\s+(\w[\w.]*)`, I believe.

To avoid matching the word inside *both* multiline and single-line comments, match the multiline comments, but do not capture them:

```
(?m)/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|^Class\s+(\w[\w.]*)
```

Or, in case the multiline comments always appear at the beginning of a line,

```
(?m)^\s*(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|Class\s+(\w[\w.]*))
```

Your value will reside in Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN7qV4/1).

Comment: what about the second type of comments /* */? This regex doesn't cover that.

Comment: Note that in case the multiline comment is part of a string literal, you may get false positives. That is why I added the 3rd pattern that will only match multiline comments that apear at the line start positions that are safe for a regex.